# Remove Script Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I hope you have well with nice pleasure.
I am trying to remove Script tag by ID. For this purpose, I am apply code

```
var elem = document.getElementById("sns_scripts");
elem.remove();
```

But, this is give me error on my console windows is :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null
```

I am trying another method is :

```
$("#sns_scripts").remove();
```

It is also not working. See Picture
[image]

Picture is mention ,  sns_scripts script still avaialbe, and above this script my custom code, but it is not working.
Please help me, I am really want to remove sns_scripts script from my webpage.

Comment: Do you have iframes? give us more html around your `script`

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why are you trying to remove in the first place? Are you aware that the script will already have been compiled?

Comment: Just looks like what you want is to remove `canplay` event listener. Because actually, your question doesn't really make sense

Comment: Dear all members,  website address is http://www.biznabler.com/

Answer (score 6):

Wrap your code within `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("sns_scripts");
    elem.remove();
});
```

Because you are trying to get an element at that point where is wasn't available in the DOM. So, it was null.

Comment: Ok but what could be the purpose of removing a `script` tag from DOM, once it has already been executed?

Comment: @A.Wolff You are right! but what i answered was different in context of the question. Well yet i am agreeing that i should have asked why OP want to do that?

Comment: Just be aware, because you answered question as stated, i din't downvote your answer :)

Comment: Dear, Actually, my website have video slider, and this script is run automatically, and I am want to custom code, so, without of removing automatically generated code, I am never customize slider.

Answer (score 1):

do not use `elem.remove()`, but use

`$(elem).remove();`

Comment: Can you please explain why not?

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Re-order following lines in your code. Because you are running remove() function before writing script with id(sns_script):

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="sns_scripts">var video=document.getElementById('bgvid');</script>
<script>
$('#sns_scripts').remove();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a script in your DOM, with custom attribute: `data-scriptid="MyDomScript"`:

```
<script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js" data-scriptid="MyDomScript"></script>
```

Then you can remove it programmatically like this:

```
let domScripts = document.querySelectorAll('[data-scriptid="MyDomScript"]');
   domScripts.forEach(function(s) {
   s.remove();
});
```

Note that this will only remove the script tag from DOM, but not completely erase the variables or events already defined by the script. You have to clear them manually.